# Filter a list of my own type - Tuples?

Tags: list, haskell, filter, wildcard, tuples

How can I filter a list of this type by the third item in the tuple:

```
type Car = (String, [String], Int [String])
```

I saw the `snd` and `fst` methods but here i dont think this will work and im not sure how to map without using the `'_'` wildcard.

Comment: I think your code is syntactically not correct. The `Int` is not right here!

Comment: You're missing a comma after `Int`.

Comment: This sounds like a rehash of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929377/format-list-output-in-haskell where record syntax and `intercalate` were already introduced.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There aren't any pre-defined functions like `fst` or `snd` for tuples with more than two elements. As you said, you can use pattern matching and the wild card `_` to do the job.

```
 cars = [ ("Foo", ["x", "y"], 2009, ["ab", "cd"]
        , ("Bar", ["z"],      1997, [])
        ]

 newCars = filter condition cars
     where condition (_, _, n, _) = n > 2005
```

However, this is usually a sign that you should change from using tuples to a record type.

```
 data Car = Car { model :: String
                , foo   :: [String]
                , year  :: Int
                , bar   :: [String] 
                }

 cars = [ Car "Foo" ["x", "y"] 2009 ["ab", "cd"]
        , Car "Bar" ["z"]      1997 []
        ]
```

Now, you can use `model`, `foo`, `year` and `bar` like you would use `fst` and `snd` on tuples.

```
 newCars = filter ((> 2005) . year) cars
```

Comment: This looks fantastic, using this method how do i use init on the list items in this type?

So for example like: last foo

This gives me a type error: Car -> [String] Does not match type : [a]??

Comment: @Ash: `last foo` won't work, because `last` wants a list whereas `foo` is a function. If you want the last `foo` of a car, you can compose the two functions as in `(last . foo) car`.

Comment: @hammer: But i am feeding into the function only 1 car from the list of cars - so that wouldn't work properly :S do you see what i mean?

Comment: @Ash: It would be good if you could be a bit more specific as to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, basically i am trying to print on screen a list of cars from a specific year. I am using last and init to help me format the outpur of the output IO (). 

I have 2 functions, one calls mapM and putStrLn on the testData and the seconf takes 1 film in and gives back the formatted string for printing to the screen. 

I am trying to add the filter so you choose which items to feed into the print function. Is that a bit clearer? Sorry im terrible at explaining sometimes.

Comment: @Ash: Maybe you should create a new question, as this is getting a bit big for the comments. Include an example of what input you have and what you want the corresponding output to be.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just use [`Data.Tuple.Utils`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MissingH/1.1.1.0/doc/html/Data-Tuple-Utils.html)?

[`MissingH`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MissingH) is full of other good stuff too; almost all of my projects use it somewhere or other.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for a similar problem:

```
  --construct a list of stock records with the number in stock less than the reorder level.

  getstock (name, stock, reorder) = stock
  getreorder (name, stock, reorder) = reorder

  check l = filter (\x ->(getstock x < getreorder x)) l

  main = print(check [("RAM",9,10),("ROM",12,10),("PROM",20,21)]); --[("RAM",9,10),("PROM",20,21)]
```

The key was to understand that the filter function takes a predicate, not a boolean value.

So, simply saying

`filter(getstock < getreorder)`

would not work,

while

`filter (getstock < 10)

would